# How do you regex this pattern?

Tags: c#, regex

Here is the pattern:

```
WORD [COLUMN] %Anything goes%
```

Basically, I need to extract the "WORD", "COLUMN" and the value between the two "%" characters.

Comment: Are WORD and PATTERN always in all caps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regular expression extracts each value into a named group.

```
(?<Word>(.*))(\s*)\[(?<Column>(.*))\]\s*%(?<Anything>(.*))%
```

Using this on your sample string should give you the following captures:

```
Word = "WORD"
Column = "COLUMN"
Anything = "Anything goes"
```

To run this regular expression and get the values, you can do something like the following (don't take this as best practise, it's just to illustrate some basic concepts).

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<Word>(.*))(\s*)\[(?<Column>(.*))\]\s*%(?<Anything>(.*))%");

Match match = regex.Match("WORD [COLUMN] %Anything goes%");

Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Word"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Column"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Anything"].Value);
```

This should output the group captures to the console. For more information on regular expressions in C#, check out MSDN documentation for [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) (this will also link to the other types that you may encounter). I also recommend [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) as a tool to help you build and analyse regular expressions. Expresso also supports code emission and various other useful features.

Comment: Are you certain this will work?  Given this first part: `(?<Word>(.*))(\s*)` and an input of "WORD  [hello] %x%" (there are two spaces), the captured word could contain 0, 1, or 2 spaces, since `.*` matches anything and `\s*` doesn't require a match at all. Wouldn't you be better off with `(?<Word>[^\s]+)\s+`?  Seems like it would be a lot less backtracking.  Similar comments for the other two parts of the expression.

Comment: @Jim: It has worked in all the testing I performed. The captures aren't greedy. However, I can see there being room for tweaks if it appears that the captures aren't quite working right.

Answer (score 3):

something like this?

First grab everything up to the first space, then grab everything between [ and ], lastly grab everything between %s

```
   ([^ ]*) \[([^\]])\] %(.*)%
```

Comment: That's not going to work, since it only takes one character for the COLUMN (I think you need `[^\]]+` there.  Also, the last part should probably be `%[^%]*%`.  Unless he allows embedded `%` characters inside "anything goes."

Answer (score 1):

```
([A-Z]+) \[([A-Z]+)\] %(.*)%
```

If word and pattern are in all caps.